Mongo DB Atlas | Aggregation not getting response
Am doing a personal project and using MongoDB Atlas for storing documents. I have the below code
    app.get('/admin/dashboard', (req, res) => {
        console.log('Received request for admin dashboard data');
        if (!dbClient || !dbClient.topology.isConnected()) {
            console.error('MongoDB is not connected');
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Database not connected' });
        }
        db.collection('registrations').aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    totalRegistrations: { $sum: { $sum: ["$numAdults", "$numKids"] } },
                    totalAdults: { $sum: "$numAdults" },
                    totalKids: { $sum: "$numKids" },
                    totalToddlers: { $sum: "$numToddlers" }
                }
            }
        ]).toArray((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Error fetching registration data:`, err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Database error' });
            }
            console.log('Aggregation result:', result);
            if (!result || result.length === 0) {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    totalRegistrations: 0,
                    totalAdults: 0,
                    totalKids: 0,
                    totalToddlers: 0
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json(result[0]);
        });
    });

This code does the aggregation. But, when I call the URL , it does not give me any info

It would be great, if veterans can help me here.

Does not it print any log ? Are you sure your registrations collection is not empty?

Its not empty. It hasa data. I tried with DataAPI, its working
